# Wordpress Membership 2 plugin's function not working in theme functions file

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, membership

How can i access membership 2 plugin's functionality in theme function's file?

```
$user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$member = new M_Membership( $user->ID ); 
print_r($member);
```

But this does not work. Can You please tell me what actions are neccessary to do this?

Comment: membership 2 plugin ? or membership  pro

Comment: What do you mean by does not work?

Comment: i want to get membership details of current user in functions file. but can't get

Answer (score 0):

Your Membership class is not there thats why you are not get this M_Membership class.

```
include_once('.\membership\app_old\membershipincludes\classes\class.membership.php');

$user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$member = new M_Membership( $user->ID ); 
print_r($member);
```